# Can I get URL parameter (set in url rule) with flask request?

Tags: python, flask

I have this url route, can I get user_id with flask.request?
I want to create a wrapper, and get the user_id here.

```
def test_required(fn):
@wraps(fn)
def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    user_id = ?????

    return fn(*args, **kwargs)

return wrapper

@app.route('/api/test/<int:user_id>', methods=['GET'])
@test_required
def jwt_routes_test(user_id):
```

request.args, request.form, or request.values not return this value.
Can I access it somehow?

Comment: your route function will provide the parameter for you.

Answer (score 2):

This code is only valid with a view function that accepts `user_id` as an argument. So, you simply get it from there.

Answer (score 1):

Use it as a parameter in your route:

```py
@app.route('/api/test/<int:user_id>', methods=['GET'])
def myroute(user_id: int):
    # do something
```

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/quickstart/#variable-rules

Comment: Thanks, but I want to get it with the Request class, I updated my question for more information

Comment: @TomposNoel maybe try `request.view_args`?

Comment: @hjpotter92 Thank you, working! Thats what I looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're asking for [`view_args`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Request.view_args) dictionary.

> A dict of view arguments that matched the request. If an exception
>   happened when matching, this will be `None`.